# How to mock chained methods on Django models

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-models, mocking, python-mock

I am trying to do something like this to mock methods on a Django model using the Python mock library:

```
# file: tasks.py
def delete_ads(user):    
    # works fine and return a list of 4 MagicMock objects
    ads = Classifieds.objects.filter(
        user=user
    )

# file: tests.py
def test_delete_ads():
    return_list = [MagicMock(name='1'), MagicMock(name='2'), MagicMock(name='3'), MagicMock(name='4')]

    with patch('user.tasks.Classifieds') as classified_mock:
        classified_mock.objects.filter.return_value = return_value
```

The above code works fine but starts returning a single MagicMock object after I change my code to this:

```
# file: tasks.py
def delete_ads(user):    
    # works fine and return a list of 4 MagicMock objects
    ads = Classifieds.objects.filter(
        user=user
    ).order_by('-added')

# file: tests.py
def test_delete_ads():
    return_list = [MagicMock(name='1'), MagicMock(name='2'), MagicMock(name='3'), MagicMock(name='4')]

    with patch('user.tasks.Classifieds') as classified_mock:
        classified_mock.objects.filter.order_by.return_value = return_value
```

Is there anyway that I can do this correctly even when I am chaining method calls on Django models?

Comment: You have a number of typos in your question. Are you sure these are not also in your code?

Comment: @Dunes Yep I am pretty sure typos are not in my code. I typed this separately.

Answer (score 1):

When mocking the return value of a mocked function you must mock the function as it would be called in the code. `parent.child` creates an attribute called `child` on the `parent` mock. Whereas, `parent().child` creates an attribute called `child` on the mocked return value of `parent()`.